# Can't open boot menu after installing mainlline kernel

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

Because of crash bugs I experienced on my Dell Inspiron, i've downloaded and installed a mainline kernel ([this one](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc8-wily/)), and the process run smoothly and without any errors.

Following [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds), after installation the kernel should be offered as a boot option on start-up. But when I restart my laptop, it boots automatically into the regular Ubuntu system, and not entering any boot-menu I can choose from.

How can I enable such menu?

Thanks.

Comment: Press the ESC or SHIFT key if you mean GRUB.

Comment: The bootloader (GRUB2) is hidden if you only have Ubuntu installed and no other OS (like Windows). To make it visible hold the SHIFT key while your computer starts up

Comment: I did hold the shift key while the computer started, and nothing changed in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `GRUB` reinstall, from your working Ubuntu install open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Where `/sdX` is your preferd partition for `GRUB`, now update `GRUB`

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should do it but if still don't see `grub` hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key just after your `bios` is shown.

Comment: welcome to AskUbuntu! As you are a new user, if this helps you please click the check mark on the left, to say thanks and allow others to find the information.